# Jekyll: different permalinks in different languages

Tags: translation, jekyll, permalinks, yaml-front-matter

I'm building my website on Jekyll in Czech and English. After launch it'll run on different domains but with same structure. But I need to have different permalinks for pages according to language.

E.g. page "About us" should be `//something/about-us/` in English and `//something/o-nas/` in Czech.

As far as my research goes I've found out that

- I can't use any other variable for permalink than specified here https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/
- I can specify permalink in frontmatter (e.g. `permalink: about-us`) but I can't make it language specific because it's not possible to use if statements in frontmatter or use any other variable (idea was something like `permalink: {{site.urls.about-us.[site.lang]}}`)...
- For each language I have different config file with different export folder. Maybe I can use that somehow?

Can anyone push me in right direciton? Maybe I'm missing something. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to look for __jekyll internationalization__ on a search engine ?

Comment: I did now, but I didn't find anything that works with current version of Jekyll.

Comment: The markdown is the content and the content is language specific and should therefore be duplicated. In what way is the permalink (or the YML) being part of this incorrect?